# Not explicitly say where all tests are

Tags: mocha.js

When setting up Mocha how can I say 'Grab all test files in the /tests/specs/ folder and run those`?

This is much more useful than having to explicitly define each test Mocha should include and run.

```
mocha.setup({
    ui: 'bdd',
    grep: 'tests/specs/*.Spec.js' // Look for all js files in specs folder
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option you can pass to `mocha.setup` to find files.

On the command line you just pass a glob pattern to Mocha (e.g. `mocha 'some/subdir/**/*.spec.js'`, the quotes are to prevent some shells from mangling the glob). You can put it in `mocha.opts` if you don't want to have to repeat it all the time. The startup script (`mocha`) will find the files and feed them to the test runner.

If you bypass Mocha's startup script but instead decide to write your own code to setup and drive Mocha, you are responsible for finding the test files and feeding them to Mocha with the `.addFile` method. An except from [this example](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically):

```
// Add each .js file to the mocha instance
fs.readdirSync(testDir).filter(function(file){
    // Only keep the .js files
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js';

}).forEach(function(file){
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join(testDir, file)
    );
});
```

You could use [`node-glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to replicate globbing functionality if you want.

In the browser, Mocha has no notion of "files" so it cannot be told what files to use. You need to use a module loader like RequireJS or SystemJS and load the modules that contain the tests or bundle all the test files with bundlers like Webpack or Browserify and load the bundle after you load Mocha. Mocha will learn of the available tests when your test files call the functions that Mocha leaks into the global space.